# How to use <intent-filter> in the receiver

Tags: android

I want to monitor the app when it is installed. I know I should use the broadcast receiver, and I also should add

```
 <receiver android:name="com.gr.xxx">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
        <data android:scheme="package"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

in the mainifest. However if I don't write this `<data android:scheme="package"/>`  it will not work.

My question is: how can I know whether  should write `<data>` or not. And   what should I write in the scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However if I don't write this  it will not work.

Correct.

Most broadcast `Intents` do not have a `Uri` filled in for the "data" facet, which is why you normally do not see `<data>` elements in `<intent-filter>` elements for `<receiver>` elements. However, the package-related broadcasts *do* put a `package:` `Uri` in the `Intent`, so you need to include that in your filter.

> how can I know whether should write  or not

In this case, the documentation for these `Intent` actions have "The data contains the name of the package". That little statement is the clue to tell you that you will need a `<data>` element. It does not tell you what the scheme is, though, which is why you wind up searching the Internet to figure out why your `<intent-filter>` does not work. I ran into this very problem a couple of days ago with these same `Intent` actions.

Ideally, the documentation would be better. Ideally, I would have hair.

> And what should I write in the scheme?

It would be the scheme(s) that might be used for the `Uri` in the `Intent`.

You will run into this more with `<activity>`, where you will see `content:` schemes a lot, `file:` schemes a lot (though decreasing), and sometimes `http:` or `https:` schemes. That is because we use a `Uri` with an `Activity` more often than use use a `Uri` with a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: The `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED` is  a system action. Where is the **source code**? Because you said "You will run into this more with <activity>" > I can't find the Intent,because I just know the action name. I don't know the package and the class.So   I can't get the Intent's code

Comment: @gus_gao_CHINA: "Where is the source code?" -- https://source.android.com somewhere. You should not need it to respond to these `Intent` actions. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Introspection/SAWMonitor for a sample project that listens for the added and replaced actions from your question.

Comment: Thanks. Just another question: For example, when I want to use this action `ACTION_MEDIA_UNMOUNTED` how can I know I should set `scheme =file` instead of `content` or something else? When I use content provider,I can get the uri in the source code(providers).

Comment: @gus_gao_CHINA: The documentation for that action has: "The path to the mount point for the unmounted media is contained in the Intent.mData field", so you know that a `<data>` element should be needed. Beyond that, you use Google and hunt for somebody who implemented a receiver for this action. And, if this is some obscure or new action for which you cannot find an existing sample, try likely candidates until you get a match, or [search the source code](http://xref.opersys.com/) for uses of the `Intent` constant to see if you can find where the `Intent` is constructed.